# Django Filtering queryset for use in a form in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm new to this stack so thought I would ask for help on what I think is a simple operation.

I have a user model class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    SA = 0
    TA = 10
    PA = 20
    DA = 30
    US = 1000
    ACL_CHOICES = (
        (SA, 'Super Admin'),
        (TA, 'Top Admin'),
        (PA, 'Parish Admin'),
        (DA, 'Parish Data Admin'),
        (US, 'User'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    access_level = models.IntegerField(choices=ACL_CHOICES, default=US)
    associated_parish = models.ForeignKey('Parish', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    associated_church = models.ForeignKey('Church', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    contact_address = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s's Profile" % self.user.username

    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def userid(self):
        return self.user.pk

    def is_superadmin(self):
        return self.access_level == UserProfile.SA

    def is_topadmin(self):
        return self.access_level == UserProfile.TA

    def is_parishadmin(self):
        return self.access_level == UserProfile.PA
```

and an admin class for use in creating gui components on heroku:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ()
    list_display = ('title', 'start_time', 'end_time')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.userprofile.associated_parish:
            return qs.filter(church__parish=request.user.userprofile.associated_parish)
        return qs

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(EventAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if request.user.userprofile.associated_parish:
            obj.parish = request.user.userprofile.associated_parish
            obj.save()

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.userprofile.associated_parish:
            if 'exclude' not in kwargs.keys():
                kwargs['exclude'] = []
            kwargs['exclude'].append('parish')
            form = super(EventAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
            form.queryset = models.Event.objects.filter(church__parish=request.user.userprofile.associated_parish)
        else:
            form = super(EventAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form
```

In the getForm function of the admin class I want to to filter the churches to return just the churches in the users parish.
I thought this line would do it:

```
form.queryset = models.Event.objects.filter(church__parish=request.user.userprofile.associated_parish)
```

But it gives me all the churches still. I am wondering what I've missed.

EDIT:
Users may or may not have parishes.
The Event model I'm using as well:

```
class Event(ScheduleEvent):

    MASS = 'MASS'
    EVENT = 'EVENT'
    CONFESSION = 'CONFESSION'

    EV_TYPE = (
        (MASS, 'Mass'),
        (EVENT, 'Event'),
        (CONFESSION, 'Confession'),
    )

    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=EV_TYPE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    church = models.ForeignKey('Church')

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.event_type == Event.MASS:
            return u"%s (%s - %s)" % (self.title, self.start.time(), self.end.time())
        else:
            date_format = u'%s' % ugettext("DATE_FORMAT")
            return ugettext('%(title)s: %(start)s - %(end)s') % {
                'title': self.title,
                'start': date(self.start, date_format),
                'end': date(self.end, date_format),
            }

    def start_time(self):
        return self.start.time()

    def end_time(self):
        return self.end.time()
```

Comment: well there is a model Event you're calling, what is it? What is the user with whom you're making test? Does he have any parrish related to him? What is Event model about ?

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the models you have defined?